# Bootstrap dropdown toggle change backbone route

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have backbone app with the Bootstrap dropdown. Unfortunately the toggle has to be a link to get styled well. So when clicking on the toggle to open the dropdown the Backbone route changes. Is there a build in way to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

So the simlpliest solution seems to use a `span` instead of a link and style it:

```
.navbar .nav > li > span.dropdown-toggle {
  float: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px;
  color: #777777;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  display: block;
}
```